# Fatal error saving CPT id to current user meta

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a CPT called contrib. When I add a contrib post, I want to insert the id for the contrib post into the user meta for the current user in an ACF (text) called contrib-id.

Here's what I have so far for my functions.php

Any idea how to fix the fatal error?

```
function save_contrib_id_to_user_meta($id, $post)
    {
        if($post->post_type != 'contrib') {
            return;
        }

    // update the current USER post 

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'contrib-id', ( $_POST['id'] ) );
    }
}    
add_action('save_post', 'save_contrib_id_to_user_meta');
```

And here's the error it's throwing

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function save_contrib_id_to_user_meta(), 1 passed in /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 289 and exactly 2 expected in /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(446) : eval()'d code:1 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(289): save_contrib_id_to_user_meta(28505) #1 /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(4153): do_action('save_post', 28505, Object(WP_Post), true) #4 /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(4244): wp_insert_post(Array, false) #5 /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(3160): wp_update_post(Array) #6 /home/customer/www/r in /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(446) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Comment: Have you created the post meta before attempting to update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `add_action`, you need to specify the number of arguments if it's more than one (since you are passing `$id` and `$post`).

Also, you could use the `save_post_{post-type}` hook, but the `save_post` will still work.

```
function save_contrib_id_to_user_meta($id, $post)
    {
        if($post->post_type != 'contrib') {
            return;
        }

    // update the current USER post 

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'contrib-id', $id ) );
    }
}
// This is the line that needs to change. Adding the argument count.    
add_action('save_post', 'save_contrib_id_to_user_meta', 10, 2);

// You could use this instead and skip the post type check
add_action('save_post_contrib', 'save_contrib_id_to_user_meta', 10, 2);
```

Comment: I took your recommendation for save_post_contrib and I looked up the reference for add_action which looks like priority should go before argument count. So I'm using:
add_action('save_post_contributors', 'save_contrib_id_to_user_meta', 10, 2);
It's not throwing an error, but it's not updating the User meta. I'm wondering if I made a mistake with $post and /or  $_POST

Comment: Whoops! Yeah, I had the priority and arguments backwards. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if it's just adding the post id to the `contrib-id` meta field, just use `$id`, you're already passing the post id using that. I updated the answer. Also, make sure your meta field is actually `contrib-id` and not `contrib_id` since ACF by default labels it with an underscore.